# design a database for a To-Do list where users can drag and drop tasks to any position

Tags: database, database-design, database-schema

how do you design a database (SQL or nonSQL) to store the order/position of each item effectively?
i tried to search by wording my questions differently but no luck, hope someone can help me here.

imagine a to do list, where you can creat/delete and re-order(by drag around) tasks to any position.

to keep it simple, you are the only user, so dont worry about userId

you can have millions of tasks, what will be an efficient design to store this position/ordering?

the best way i can think of is to have a large number for the position:

| task_id | position |
| --- | --- |
| Task1 | 100000 |
| Task2 | 200000 |
| Task3 | 300000 |

add Task4 inbetween Task1 and Task2:

| task_id | position |
| --- | --- |
| Task1 | 100000 |
| Task4 | 150000 |
| Task2 | 200000 |
| Task3 | 300000 |

move Task3 inbetween Task1 and Task4:

| task_id | position |
| --- | --- |
| Task1 | 100000 |
| Task3 | 125000 |
| Task4 | 150000 |
| Task2 | 200000 |

new position = (position above + position below) /2
but eventually it will run out, and its not scalable

i can have the position to be a varChar with lots of digits or even mix with letters,

but is there anyother way to solve this problem?

thanks

Comment: A six-digit position value is sufficient for 32 shifts.  If you anticipate more than 32 shifts, run a job occasionally to renumber the position values.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have integer. You can do this in about two queries.

```
#
# Take the current position of the element and the desired position element
# Then add the base increment(1 in your case 100000) to all the position
# between desired and current position
#
UPDATE tasks 
       SET 
            position = position + 100000
       WHERE 
            position >= 200000 AND position <= 400000;

# Now update your task to the desired value
UPDATE tasks 
       SET 
            position = 200000 
       WHERE 
            task_id = 4;
```

That will update all your position to have the required position you want. I have not benchmarked it but this should work reasonably well for about 10K datas.